# How can I create a tree structure in comand line that ONLY display the folders of that directory

Tags: command-line, tree-view

I want to create a word file that displays the tree structure of my music folder.
I only want to list the folders. For now I'm using the command line:

```
tree /f >tree.
```

By using that command line the `*.mp3` files also get listed.
How can I visualize only the folders as a tree on windows?

Comment: Use `tree > tree.txt` it will not report the files. PS> welcome on Super User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simply (without the `/f`)

```
tree > tree.txt
```

and then import the `file.txt` in Word.

---

The general syntax of the command <sup>[[1](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tree.mspx?mfr=true)],[[2](http://www.computerhope.com/treehlp.htm)]</sup> is

> tree [Drive:][Path] [/f] [/a]

and the option `/f` is used to show the filenames too.

> /f    Displays file names in each directory.